# PHP Email with Static and Variable CC

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to create an email form where some addresses are fixed, and additional ones are variable, taken from a text field.

Is is possible to concatenate the CC header in such a way?

```
$headers .= "CC: fixed@email.com, fixed@email2.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: ".$additional_emails."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you're doing it wrong.

```
$headers .= "CC: fixed@email.com, fixed@email2.com";
$headers .= ", ". $additional_emails;
$headers .= "\r\n";
```

- Assuming `$additional_emails` is comma separated.

It also be worth while checking to see if `$additional_emails` has a value.

```
$headers .= "CC: fixed@email.com, fixed@email2.com";
if( strlen($additional_emails) > 0 ) {
   $headers .= ", ". $additional_emails;
}
$headers .= "\r\n";
```

If `$additional_emails` is an array, you can use `implode()`.

```
$headers .= "CC: fixed@email.com, fixed@email2.com";
if( count($additional_emails) > 0 ) {
   $headers .= ", ". implode(",", $additional_emails);
}
$headers .= "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Tray it

$to = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject = "Hii";
    $message = "";
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <abs@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: xyz@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,'.$email. "\r\n";
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```